# Why are all the colors the same?

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't understand why all the colors give the same result. All the textviews background draw in gray, although I have black, white and red. What is the problem here?

```
<color name="color1">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="color2">#000000</color>
    <color name="color3">#FF0000</color? 


Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        map.put(R.id.color1,R.color.color1);
        map.put(R.id.color2,R.color.color2);
        map.put(R.id.color3,R.color.color3);
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable;
        TextView textView;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            textView = findTextView(entry.getKey());
            gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) textView.getBackground().mutate();
            gradientDrawable.setColor(entry.getValue());
            gradientDrawable.invalidateSelf();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to:

```
gradientDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(entry.getValue()));
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColor%28int%29)

The parameter it takes is:

> *argb* The color used to fill the shape

By passing it the `R` resource int directly it's basically a random number generated by `R`. You need to "decode it" into a 0xAARRGGBB colour value using `Resources.getColor()`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29)

They probably all look the same because the ints are close to each other in value.